# Could the body of the Sandbox question serve as a directory to all of the answers?

Tags: discussion, sandbox

I feel like one of the main difficulties of having a massive sandbox is the difficulty of seeing all of the posts in the sandbox.  There are 63 answers in the XIV sandbox and 66 in the XII sandbox, and I'm pretty sure I've never actually seen most of those submissions.

To increase the visibility of all of the sandbox posts, I think the body of the sandbox question could provide a list of all of the active sandbox submissions.  When people casually open the sandbox, they might see something that catches their eye.

When a person adds a sandbox answer, they add a link to their answer to the directory.  When a challenge is posted, the user moves the link to the list of completed answers.

This is basically what I envision it looking like:

> **Active Works-In-Progress**
>
> - [Draw square numbers in the shape of circles](http://www.example.com/)
> - [1000 blank white cards KotH tournament](http://www.example.com/)
> - [Compute Graham's Number in Manufactoria](http://www.example.com/)
>
> **Posted Challenges**
>
> - [3D render your program's source code](http://www.example.com/)
> - [Potato Farming KOTH](http://www.example.com/)

Slight side note: I am using the [ ] ( )  form the links.

```
 - [Title of Answer](URL to answer)
```

The use of the question as a directory has the advantage of recording the history of sandbox use, so that everyone can see exactly what posts are contained in the sandbox and where they are in development.

It would be convenient if there were a way to automate this.  For now, I think this is something that the community is capable of maintaining, similar to how people already edit their sandbox posts to denote a posted challenge.

Comment: I don't even think we'd need a list of posted challenges. You can find them all on main. But we can split the active ones in two or three categories depending on whether the spec is still incomplete, a controller (or similar) still needs to be written or everything is done and the OP is only looking for feedback. Alternatively, group by challenge type.

Comment: If you can't decide between groupings, just have two sets of labels. List the posts as `Title [status] [challenge type]`.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I have taken the liberty of compiling a directory to all of the active submissions in Sandbox XIV.  I have not included posted/deleted answers, and I have not categorized them at all.  This should help reduce the workload needed to update the sandbox if we decide to do this.

**Sandbox XIV Active Posts**

- [Code with largest MD5 hash of output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2024/2867)
- [Pecking Birds - input wanted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2008/2867)
- [Realistic Stock Market](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2010/2867)
- [Tetromino Game](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2009/2867)
- [Transport Tycoon [under construction]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1965/2867)
- [Five Miscellaneous Question Ideas](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2007/2867)
- [Self-Enumerating Pangram](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2001/2867)
- [Cross language mania](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1995/2867)
- [Conspiracy theory: find fuzzy anagrams](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1982/2867)
- [Chess: End Game KOTH](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1981/2867)
- [Epic Customizable Tank Battle (Work-In-Progress)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1925/2867)
- [Teach me to play clarinet](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1964/2867)
- [Morse Decode Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1958/2867)
- [Hexiled (Clone) King of the Hill/Code Challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1963/2867)
- [Diplomacy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1954/2867)
- [Balanced Ternary Converter](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1945/2867)
- [Tennis Tournament (Incomplete)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1943/2867)
- [The Painter's Predicament](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1937/2867)
- [Paired Programming: Down Periscope!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1942/2867)
- [Multiplayer Game of Life (GOL)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1938/2867)
- [Underwater Survival Game](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1904/2867)
- [Dining Philosophers (Incomplete)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1882/2867)
- [Implement nl](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1928/2867)
- [Traders](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1923/2867)
- [The Symbols vs. The Letters](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1932/2867)
- [Find a multiple of 42 that is spelled with all of the characters that make up the word "forty-two".](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1931/2867)
- [Program calculating its own length](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1926/2867)
- [Display a Magic Square](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1901/2867)
- [Generate a random work of art](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1924/2867)
- [Domino Circuits](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1903/2867)
- [Comment Driven Stats for Stack Exchange Questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1921/2867)
- [Morra, the Noble Game of Kings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1893/2867)
- [Global Warming](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1891/2867)
- [El Farol Jail : The Game Of Happyness](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1871/2867)
- [Your love you want to show 'em, generate them a poem.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1897/2867)
- [Shuffle the system word list...repairably](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1857/2867)
- [Play Wythoff's Nim Perfectly](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1902/2867)
- [Brainfuck compression](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1881/2867)
- [Find the mines!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1884/2867)
- [Reindent Java/C/C++/etc. code](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1879/2867)
- [Find the Greatest Common Divisor of two numbers, with no math operators or calls to math libraries.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1880/2867)
- [Yet Another Pi Question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1870/2867)
- [ASCII: Art or Math(s)?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1863/2867)
- [Type me out.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1849/2867)

Comment: Looking at the size of this thing, we definitely need a rule that the community will remove posts after an inactivity of 2 weeks (say) and leave a comment on the proposal to inform the poster that he's welcome to edit it back into the overview if he still intends to post the challenge.