# Remove numbering from sandbox title?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, sandbox

It seems (from [this meta thread](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2058/how-should-sandbox-retirement-be-handled-if-at-all)) that we are no longer intending to retire sandboxes, and I now approve of this plan. Because the answers can be sorted by activity, old posts will not clutter the sandbox and there is no need to retire it.

Now that [Mark XIII](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1596/16402) has been retired, and the only one currently active is [Mark XIV](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1847/16402), it shouldn't cause confusion to remove the number from the title of Mark XIV.

If the current sandbox will not be retired, it makes sense not to leave the numbering stuck at XIV forever. The numbers in the title imply that sandboxes are going to be retired eventually, but if this is no longer the case, it is worth changing the title of the Mark XIV sandbox to reflect that it is now The Ultimate And Final Sandbox.

It was also mentioned elsewhere on meta that the numbers confuse new users.

## Should the numbering be removed from the title of the current sandbox?

Comment: There hasn't been *that* much support for the idea of not retiring the sandbox yet, but I thought it was understood that we'd just have *the* sandbox if that is accepted. In fact, Doorknob already said in that case he'd go through all the old ones, delete posted challenges, then merge them into a single "Old Sandbox" or something like that. The only thing that needs to be decided is if we want to start fresh, or turn sandbox XIV into *the* sandbox. And that will probably depend on how much we want to change sandbox policies. I'll turn this into an answer if the other discussion is settled.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, a difference of two votes (one of which is mine) is in no way a consensus. It's still not entirely clear what we're eventually going to do with the sandboxes.

That said, if we *do* end up choosing the "one sandbox to rule them all<sup>*</sup>" thing, there would probably be two likely options:

1. Merge all the current sandboxes together, and this merged post now becomes The One Sandbox
2. Merge all the current sandboxes together, create a new one, and the new one becomes The One Sandbox; the old one becomes Sandboxes of Ancient Times or something

We would only take the second option if we feel that there are already too many posts in the old sandboxes to continue adding on to.

---

<sup>*:
*One Sandbox to rule them all, One Sandbox to find them

One Sandbox to bring them all, and in the darkness merge them*

<sub>*(in the Land of Meta where the Shadows lie)*</sub></sup>

Comment: +1 for LotR reference. :-D

Comment: *We would only take the second option if we feel that there are already too many posts in the old sandboxes to continue adding on to.* If we came to that conclusion the new model wont work for long - or it would mean that we expected less new challenges than those posted in the Sandboxes of Ancient Times.

Comment: @Howard It would still be nice as a clean slate, especially if we want to change some policies (like deleting posted challenges instead of just editing them down).

Comment: @MartinBüttner The statement contained the word *only*. Your suggestion is clearly different from the one quoted in my comment.